# Install mbstring on Fedora 26

Tags: linux, php-5.6, php-7.1, mbstring, fedora-26

I have Downgraded php7.1 to php5.6. and I need to install mbstring.
I tried with below command. Its not wkirking.

```
dnf install php56-php-mbstring
```

Error was:

```
Error: Unable to find a match
```

Comment: And? Did you try listing all packages with "mbstring" in it?

Comment: Yes .i tried that also.

Comment: `php56-php-mbstring` is available for Fedora 23, 24, 25, 27 .... from the remi.repo http://rpms.famillecollet.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download rpm file from [here](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/fedora/26/remi/x86_64/)
   [image]
2. add rpm to system
   `su`

   `rpm -Uvh php56-php-mcrypt-5.6.32-1.fc26.remi.x86_64.rpm`
3. `dnf install  php56-php-mbstring`

I succeeded using by above method.